# cmake detect unknown target listed in target_link_libraries

Tags: cmake

It seems that cmake is not able to detect targets that do not exist. Honestly I was surprised to found that out.

```
target_link_libraries(Foo
  PRIVATE
    Bar
    Car
)
```

If the library `Car` doesn't exist, I would expect that cmake returns an error at configuration time. Unfortunately this is not the case. Or is the behavior voluntary?

I use cmake version 3.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first argument to `target_link_libraries` **required** to be a *target*, other argument *may* be a target, but may be other things as well. Possible types of non-first arguments are described in the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_link_libraries.html):

- A library target name
- A full path to a library file
- A plain library name
- A link flag

(keywords are omitted in that list).

In you case CMake interprets `Car` as a plain library name, so it will pass option `-lCar` to the linker.

Note, that CMake doesn't try to interpret the linker's flags.

Comment: Yes it make sense!